# Parsing a UL LI list to comma separated values

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

As it is right now, my function spits out my UL LI list as the below:

```
Coffee ,Tea ,Milk
```

I need to get it into the format of:

```
Coffee,Tea,Milk
```

Why does it add the extra spaces?

```
function items_2_var() {

    var x = document.getElementById("list1").getElementsByTagName("li")

    var values = []

    for(var i=0;i < x.length; i++) {

        if (x[i].innerText.length) { values.push(x[i].innerText) }
    }

    alert(values.join(","))

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="list1">
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not get the same problem. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/6uTVD/

Comment: verify that you actually did values.join(",") and not values.join(" ,") (?)

Comment: Note `innerText` is non-standard, and not supported on Firefox. I can't reproduce the problem using standard `textContent` on Firefox.

Comment: It seems the problem lies with renaming the file from a .htm to .hta. Weird that it would cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce the problem you describe is if you actually end up with an HTML rendered as so:

```
<div id="list1">
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
      <li>Tea&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
      <li>Milk&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In that case, yo do see the space when you join the strings. However, this is easy to fix by using the following instead: `values.push((x[i].innerText.replace(/\s/g,''))`

Code:

```
function items_2_var() {
    var x = document.getElementById("list1").getElementsByTagName("li");
    var values = [];
    for(var i=0;i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].innerText.length) { values.push((x[i].innerText.replace(/\s/g,''))); }
    }
    alert(values.join(","));
}
```

[Full demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6uTVD/1/)